# Optimizing transfer between video memory and system memory

Tags: audio, memory, glsl, gpu, synthesizer

Some time ago, I was experimenting with creating a heavy duty sound-synth on the GPU by using GLSL. The synth was capable of generating very complex sounds over 256+ simultaneous voices.
On the CPU, I wouldn't dare to dream to get this kind of performance.

(simplified explanation) To generate the sounds, I have a floating-point texture of NxV size. N = number of samples, V = number of voices. A synth-shader generates values for every texel.

A second shader will then mix all the voices together in a 16-bit signed integer 1D texture (or whatever format the sound card requires). This final texture is copied as fast as possible to system memory using pixel buffers after which it is sent out to the sound-card.

For sound, I use the super-low-latency Windows Core Audio.

I wrote a MIDI interface to be able to play on a midi keyboard connected to the PC and it works perfectly when using the Intel GPU with a latency of only 3ms (N = 132 samples, which is a lot better than the required 15-20ms N=600-900 samples). But when using the NVidia GPU to be able to support even more heavier computations, the latency is much bigger (>35ms N=>1500 samples).

I understand that the reason is that when using the Intel GPU, the rendering is done on system memory directly and copying that texture is very fast, but when using the NVidia GPU, rendering is being done in video memory and copying from video memory to system memory is a bottleneck, even though it is only about some 4KB of audio data that should be transferred (which doesn't even come close to 6GB/s that the hardware should be capable of).

Is there a way to improve this? Is it for example possible to have the NVidia GPU render directly tot system memory (at acceptable speed), or what are those fameous shared memories they talk about in OpenCL? Would OpenCL improve this? (I have no experience with OpenCL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it's faster to for the GPU to write to main memory instead of the CPU reading VRAM. The way you do that is with PBOs, have a look [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html). You have to hint for the PBO to be stored in main memory. This may or may not be helpful and depends on hardware architecture.

OpenCL is not inherently faster. If you have a clean implementation in OpenGL, chances are you are not going to gain a speed improvement with an OpenCL implementation. But there are things you can do in OpenCL that you cant with OpenGL.

A couple of other suggestions if you still find that bandwidth is your bottleneck:

1. Are you avoiding as much blocking as you can? When you are reading a texture with a GL call in a thread, are you also processing the last read texture in another thread, things like this. Note that calls to glGetTexImage are async, and wont block. It's only until you call glMapBuffer, that you will block and know the transfer is done.
2. Are you transferring the least you can possibly transfer, the least amount of times.
3. there are compressed texture formats that are lossy, but maybe are suitable for your needs?

Comment: Can you give me more info on the first thing you say: have the GPU write to main memory? I have 2 swapping framebuffers with textures in it to where the GPU renders the sound data. I use PBO's to copy the framebuffer data to system memory. I don't understand how I can change the PBO's to make the GPU store in system memory instead. Do I need to render immediately to a PBO instead of a texture? Are there examples of this?

Comment: As for your suggestions: 1. I think I am avoiding all possible blocking: the system has been designed so that when a sound buffer is requested, it should already have been transferred with a PBO (which seems to be the problem). 2. yes, I believe so. 3. I understand, but the data is already so very small, I think the bottleneck is more the initiation of the transfer than the transfer itself. That's why I am very eager to find out how to render to system memory directly.

Comment: @scippie see [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44783/opengl-sluggish-performance-in-extracting-texture-from-gpu) and  [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object) for more info on setting up PBO

Comment: having GPU write to main memory is just a hint, it may or may not be helpful. Note that calls to glGetTexImage are async, and wont block. It's only until you call glMapBuffer, that you will block and know the transfer is done.

Comment: Thanks, I knew all that and I already used it, except for the READ_STREAM hint. For some reason, I used WRITE_DYNAMIC. I don't remember why. I will try it out later. Too bad it's just a hint and the driver may choose to do otherwise. It will never give me any certainty.